# Getting Issue with Source Cache in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui, rx.net

I have one issue in subscribing to source cache. Let me describe the problem.
Lets say I have Test Class

```
public class Test {
    public bool feature1 {get; set;} = false;
    public bool feature2 {get; set; } = false;
    public string name;
    public Test(string name){
       this.name = name
    }
}
```

I want to see the changes happening in the property of test class and subscriber react according to change. But with current Implementation getting notification only when source is getting updated with new data not if any property of element in source cache is getting updated.

```
class Notifier {
    public SourceCache<Test, string> testClassNotifier = new SourceCache<Test, string>(x => x.Name);
    public Notifier(){
        Task.Run(() => 
           {
             this.AddOrUpdateSourceCache();
             this.SubscribeTestObj1();
             this.SubscribeTestObj2();
         }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
   
     private AddOrUpdateSourceCache() 
     {
       List<Test> testListObj = new List<Test>() { new Test("test1"), new Test("test2") };
       for (Test obj : testListObj) {
          this.testClassNotifier.AddOrUpdate(obj); 
       }
       Task.Run(async () => {
            for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
                this.testListObj[i].feature1 = true;
                await Task.Delay(4000).ConfigureAwait(false);
                // I want here to my get the notification in change with intial values as well.
            }
       }).ConfiguareAwait(false);
     }
     
    private IObservable<Test,string> GetNotification(string name){
        // which api should use here ?? Or any way I can use `WhenAny` here.
        return this.testClassNotifier.Watch(name);
    } 
    private SubscribeTestObj1() {
        this.GetNotification("test1").Subscribe(obj => // do something);
    }

    private SubscribeTestObj1() {
        this.GetNotification("test2").Subscribe(obj => // do something);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution: implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Test` class, and use `AutoRefresh()`

Example:

```c#
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    bool _feature1 = false;
    public bool feature1 
    { 
        get => _feature1; 
        set 
        {
            _feature1 = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new(nameof(feature1)));       
        }
    }
    // ... see the rest of the class in OP's question
}
```

Test:

```c#
var source = new SourceCache<Test, string>(x => x.name);

var a = new Test("a");
var b = new Test("b");

source
    .Connect()
    .AutoRefresh()
    .Watch(b.name)
    .Subscribe(change => Console.WriteLine($"Reason: <{change.Reason}> feature1: <{change.Current.feature1}>"));

source.AddOrUpdate(a);
source.AddOrUpdate(b);
b.feature1 = true;
```

Output:

```
Reason: <Add> feature1: <False>
Reason: <Refresh> feature1: <True>
```

Comment: cool, i will try that, any good place to learn reactiveX with .net,

also will it provide the intial value to subscriber as well the change.

Comment: I've used [Introduction to Rx](http://introtorx.com/) and [ReactiveX.io](https://reactivex.io/). For reactiveui, I've been using their website and also [Kent Boogarts book](https://kent-boogaart.com/you-i-and-reactiveui/)

As you can se from the output, the inital is in the output, happened when `b` was added.

Comment: what is here ` .Watch(b.name)` b.name, it is now tied to specific object in a list, what i want to rather watch it on entire list.

Comment: Some options are `.Bind()` or `.AsObservableCache()`.  More details in his [github repo](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData#consuming-observable-change-sets)